# Laravel Inertia returns blank on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, breeze, inertiajs

is there other/proper way to deploy laravel-inertia app in shared hosting?

cause i'm encountering this when I upload the app on the server.

it only show '@routes' as string.

[image]

Comment: upload app.js properly

Comment: Same here, following the example-app documentation, this is on my local docker using sails. @Dips a little expansion would be helpful.

Comment: @jp.palubs Did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue:

```
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

The variable "route" is undefined.

It's also trying to load bundle.js from localhost:8080 in app.blade but port 8080 isn't used in sail, and bundle.js doesn't exist at all in the project.

I'm following this to the letter using breeze and Vue: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze